# destroy a deezer Event Destroy (DZ.Event.subscribe('player_paused') etc

Tags: deezer

I use the deezer api to build a web app and User a DZ.Event.subscribe('player_paused'). There is only a description to add a new Event, not to destroy. Now the simple Question is: How to destroy this Event?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function: DZ.Event.unsubscribe('EVNT_NAME');