# Unsubscribe specific subscription with Deezer Javascript SDK DZ.Event.unsubscribe

Tags: javascript, deezer

In the Deezer Javascript SDK, the `DZ.Event.unsubscribe` method can be used to [unsubscribe all subscriptions for a specific event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654612/destroy-a-deezer-event-destroy-dz-event-subscribeplayer-paused-etc), but is there any way to unsubscribe a specific subscription instead of all of them?

The `DZ.Event.subscribe` method doesn't return any ID that could be given in the unsubscription call, and sending the subscription callback function to the unsubscription method doesn't work either:

```
function callback(args) {
  console.log('GOT player_position 1', args);
}
DZ.Event.subscribe('player_position', callback);
DZ.Event.subscribe('player_position', args => {
  console.log('GOT player_position 2', args);
});
DZ.Event.unsubscribe('player_position', callback); // Unsubscribes both subscriptions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are currently only *nasty* ways to do this with access to `DZ.Event.callbacks`

For instance you can:

```
//declare your own unsubscribe function
var unsubscribe = (event, callback) => {
    if(DZ.Event.callbacks[event]) {
        let index = DZ.Event.callbacks[event].indexOf(callback); //find the index of your callback
        if(index !== -1) {
            DZ.Event.callbacks[event].splice(index, 1); //remove it
        }
    }
}
```